# F# singleton for generic type with static constraint

Tags: generics, f#

I wonder if it is possible to create a singleton for generic type with static constraint (the third type below will not compile). Adding `inline` to the members of third type does not work. Thanks a lot!

```
type A private () = 
    static let instance = A ()
    static member Instance = instance
    member this.DoNothing (x : int) = 0


type GenericA<'B> private () =
    static let instance = GenericA<'B> ()
    static member Instance = instance
    member this.DoNothing (x : 'B) = 0


type GenericWithStaticConstraintA<'B when 'B : (static member MyMember : Unit -> int)> private () =
    static let instance = GenericWithStaticConstraintA<'B> ()
    static member Instance = instance
    member this.DoNothing (x : 'B) = 0
```

Comment: Why not use an interface that has Mymember which 'B implements?

Answer (score 4):

You can use statically resolved type constraints on classes for static members, by means of the `inline` keyword.

```
type GenericWithStaticConstraintA< ^B when ^B : (static member MyMember : unit -> int)> =
    static member inline DoNothing(x : ^B) = 0
```

Example:

```
type Foo = Foo with static member MyMember() = 42
type Bar = Bar with static member MyMember = fun () -> 42
GenericWithStaticConstraintA.DoNothing(Foo)
GenericWithStaticConstraintA.DoNothing(Bar) // The type 'Bar' does not support the operator 'MyMember'
```

You could also do this with instance members (`member inline __.DoNothing(x : ^B) = 0`), but what would be the point of it?

Comment: The issue is with the singleton. I mentioned that adding inline does not work. As soon as you add it to the original example, the compile starts to fail on `static member inline Instance = instance`. Anyway, I found a workaround for the task that I needed.

Comment: A generic instance _will_ be created in the static contructor, the `static let` compiles to something like `Script1.GenericWithStaticConstraintA<B> genericWithStaticConstraintA = new Script1.GenericWithStaticConstraintA<B>();`. How useful is this outside the constructor, lest you supply a concrete type, similarly to an instantiation on module level? And would you care to show your workaround and answer your question yourself?